# Annoying dynamic_reconfigure code regeneration on catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, make, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The dynamic reconfigure code generation looks it is being executed unconditionally even if the python generation script (.cfg) did not change.

This means that everytime that catkin_make command is called  some new header (.h) files are generated by the dynamic_reconfigure cmake functionality. Because of this, the "incremental build mechanism" of cmake gets broken and your *.cpp files that depens on those headers recompile. This may make the development process slower.

Is this the expected behavior of the dynamic_reconfigure code generation system?
Is there any way to avoid breaking the incremental build of cmake?

Until the current moment I have worked with these approaches (but I would like to avoid them because they do not satisfy me totally):

- the dynamic reconfigure files to other project  and use the  catkin_make's "black package list"
- building manually the targets I need the catkin_make's "--pkg" flag

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237057/annoying-dynamic_reconfigure-code-regeneration-on-catkin_make/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dynamic_reconfigure should not regenerate the headers unless the .cfg file actually changes.

Basic reasons for generating headers each time can be:

- file name doesn't match the class name, so cmake doesn't detect that the headers have been generated
- using the rosbuild generator with catkin

Have a look at http://answers.ros.org/question/165426/generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options-executed-every-build/ for another discussion of this topic.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2016-06-15**:
Really worked. Thanks.
This small detail can really decrease the development productivity.